# Text Overlap in Amazon widget on Wordpress site & Firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have a wordpress powered website, http://techpatrol.eu

On it, the Amazon search widget in the right hand sidebar overlaps the text over the images.  I've tried playing around with various different options and sizes on Amazon, but if I want images they seem to overlap no matter what options I set.

Does anyone know how I might solve this?  It doesn't happen in Chrome, but just under half of my visitors use firefox, so I'd like to get it to look right.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Bump - anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Anyone?  Someone must know what the answer to this is?